# SMTP Client , should my customers change it for their own?

Tags: c#

I am sending an email like this from my console app, the value for `Subject, SMTP, e`tc.. as you see in the code are configurable from the App.Config file so customer can type their own.

```
     SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SmtpHost"]);
     client.Port = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SmtpPort"]);
     client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
     client.Send(message);
```

I entered my own `SMTP, Port`, etc.. info in the config file when I tested the application. Now that the customer wants to run it, do they have to type their own Port, SMTP, etc.. or still can use what I have typed there and just change the `RecipientAddresses`?

**NOTE**: It doesn't have to be an email address that they can actually reply to. The program just needs to send a report after running to their real email address. It doesn't matter if the sender email address is real or not.

Comment: That depends - does the client want to send it from their own email or from an email you provide?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum  It doesn't have to be an email address that they can actually reply to. The program just needs to send a report after running to their real email address. It doesn't matter if the sender email address is real or not

Comment: In that case - as long as they're OK with it and you're OK with them being able to send arbitrary emails from that email account - they don't have to send it from their own emails. I'd recommend you set up a web server that accepts requests from the client instead so they can't set arbitrary things on that email but it'll work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is, "It depends."

If you want to give the client your SMTP credentials, and if your SMTP server is accessible from the client's site, then leaving your settings is just fine. I would caution *against* doing that, though, for a number of reasons:

1. The client is now tied to your SMTP service. If you shut down that server or your credentials change, then the client won't be able to send mail.
2. The client has your SMTP credentials. Somebody could get those credentials from the config file and do bad things with your account.
3. If your client decides to spam others using your credentials, your SMTP service could get marked as a spammer, and nobody will be able to send email from your account.

All things considered, you're much better off having your clients use their own SMTP settings for this.

Comment: Thanks, so basically I tell them ask your IT guy and in the config file enter your own SMTP Host and Port# ?

Comment: @ConfusedSleepyDeveloper: Yes, that's what I would do. Also note that their SMTP service might require credentials (user name and password), so you might have to modify your program to support that. Also, if your SMTP service it accessible from outside your firewall, you should configure it to require credentials. Otherwise you have an "open relay" and anybody (including spammers) can send messages through it.